# How to change the url of a page from a dropdown in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to be able to change the value of a wordpress page url according to a selected value from a dropdown list via a custom post type.

I want to use several dropdowns such that "Country" then "State" then "City" then "Town" will change the url to the selected values.

If i select just the country then the url will look like

`http://example.com/india`

When i select states of india in addition to that then the url will look like `http://example.com/india/delhi`.

Please reference this page to see an example of what I am trying to do:
http://areapincode.in/

Comment: Cleaned up the grammer, made the description of issue concise, removed incorrect tag, added correct tag, removed noise ("thanks"), and made the question easier to find by others looking for the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for URL rewrite in WordPress. Please see the following link for more detail,

[WordPress URL Rewrite](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/)

It works like following,

1. Add action hook for rewrite,

   add_action( 'init', 'rewrites_init', 1, 0);

   function rewrites_init() {
       add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?&country=$matches[1](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/)&state=$matches[2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)&city=$matches[3]&town=$matches[4]', 'top');
   }
2. Set rewrite tags

   add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
   function custom_rewrite_tag() {
       add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
       add_rewrite_tag('%state%', '([^&]+)');
       add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)');
       add_rewrite_tag('%town%', '([^&]+)');
   }
3. Set query vars

   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars');
   public function query_vars($query_vars) {
       $query_vars[] = 'country';
       $query_vars[] = 'state';
       $query_vars[] = 'city';
       $query_vars[] = 'town';
       return $query_vars;
   }
4. After that you can get the values by `get_query_var`
   [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

This is not tested. But with your little effort this can be helpful. LEt me know in the comments below.

Comment: hi @dipak, can you please tell me in which way i can do this task, in custom post type or anything else, because if i create a custom post type, i can create country as taxonomy and state as post name, then how can i select city and town after state?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<select id="city" name="city">
<option value="mumbai">mumbai</option>
<option value="delhi">delhi</option>
<option value="surat">surat</option>
<option value="ahmedabad">ahmedabad</option>
</select>
```

**Call jquery:**

```
$('#city').change(function(){
  var city = $(this).val();
  window.location.href='your url'+city;
});
```